# Swift accelerometer data don't update UILabel shadow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want change shadow position of the UILabel by using accelerometer data. I already successfully see the accelerometer data in the console output, but the shadow doesn't want to update self position. All that I have is different shadow position when the app launch.

I need update it every second or frequently.

The code about applying shadow position is:

```
self.bigLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: (14 - data.acceleration.y*5), height: (14 - data.acceleration.z*5))
```

What i'm doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var bigLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.bigLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 61/255, green: 88/255, blue: 126/255, alpha: 0.8).CGColor
    self.bigLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    self.bigLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1


    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable{
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()


        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler:
            {(data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

                self.bigLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: (14 - data.acceleration.y*5), height: (14 - data.acceleration.z*5))

                println("X = \(data.acceleration.x)")
                println("Y = \(data.acceleration.y)")
                println("Z = \(data.acceleration.z)")

            }

        )
    } else {
        println("Accelerometer is not available")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're receiving updates on a background queue and you can't update UI elements from anything but the main queue. The easiest solution is to simply change the queue you're passing to `motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue` to the main queue:

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler: ...
```

However, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:) states:

> Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the
>   main operation queue is not recommended.

So you should probably set [`accelerometerUpdateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerUpdateInterval) to something other than the default. It'll depend on your application, of course, but something like `1.0 / 30.0` might be a good value to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the `shadowOffset` of the layer.

Try doing this :

`self.bigLabel.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: (14 - data.acceleration.y*5), height: (14 - data.acceleration.z*5))`